# Reduce empty space in ggnet2 network plot

Tags: r, networking, graph, ggally, ggnet2

I'm plotting the network graph pictured below using R and [GGally::ggnet2](https://briatte.github.io/ggnet/).

You can see that there are several independent clusters disconnected from each other and these are quite spread out leaving a lot of empty space on the figure. Is it possible to make these clusters closer to each other thus making better use of the space?

[image]

Code to reproduce:

```
# Get datafile
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/h4kt2fw1j4hdw3a/matrix.tsv

R
library(GGally)
library(network)

mat <- read.table('matrix.tsv')
net <- network(mat)
ggnet2(net, size= 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Trying different layouts might prove effective:

```
library(GGally)
library(network)

ggnet2(net,
       size= 1,
       mode = "kamadakawai")
```

[image]

or you can experiment with the parameters of a specific layout using the `layout.par` argument

```
ggnet2(net,
       size= 1,
       mode = "fruchtermanreingold",
       layout.par = list(repulse.rad = 100,
                         area = 1000))
```

[image]

for a complete list of options see [?sna::gplot.layout](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sna/versions/2.6/topics/gplot.layout)

Too find a pleasing layout you will need to experiment a bit with the options since they depend on the graph. To cite a part of the help [?sna::gplot.layout](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sna/versions/2.6/topics/gplot.layout):

> Vertex layouts for network visualization pose a difficult problem –
> there is no single, “good” layout algorithm, and many different
> approaches may be valuable under different circumstances.

```
set.seed(1234)
ggnet2(net,
       size= 1,
       mode = "fruchtermanreingold",
       layout.par = list(repulse.rad = 300,
                         area = 1200))
```

[image]

Another option is using [visNetwork](https://datastorm-open.github.io/visNetwork/) and after finding a good initial layout manually moving some vertices

Comment: Thanks- these are a lot better. However, clusters occasionally end up intersecting each other, which can be misleading. Do you know of any solution explicitly designed to nicely arrange disconnected clusters?

Comment: for each specific case you will need to experiment a bit to find what looks best.